# How to add a user to multiple groups in alpine linux

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am creating a docker container using alpine as the base image and I have created a user using the following command:
`RUN adduser -u 5532 -s /bin/tcsh -D userA`
and I have already defined few groups as

```
RUN addgroup --gid 2076 groupA && \
    addgroup --gid 2077 groupB && \
    addgroup --gid 400 groupC
```

I am unable to assign the created user to multiple groups using `adduser` command. If I have multiple `adduser` command/instruction I am getting an error `user userA is in use`. Please let me know how can I assign a particular user to multiple groups in alpine linux.

Complete `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:alpine3.16
RUN adduser -u 5532 -s /bin/tcsh -D userA
RUN addgroup --gid 2076 groupA && \
    addgroup --gid 2077 groupB && \
    addgroup --gid 400 groupC
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `addgroup` command can be used to add a user to a group by passing the user as first argument:

```
FROM python:alpine3.16
RUN adduser -D userA
RUN addgroup groupA && addgroup userA groupA
RUN addgroup groupB && addgroup userA groupB
USER userA
```

So first create a group with `addgroup <GROUP>` then add the user to the group with `addgroup <USER> <GROUP>`.

Comment: Or use modgroup to add a secondary group to the user. usermod -a -G groupA userA

Comment: @sleepyhead Alpine doesn't have the `usermod` command.

Comment: Yes it does with the shadow package, "apk add  shadow", https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=usermod&path=&name=shadow&branch=edge&arch=x86_64

Comment: Well ok, the base image doesn't have `usermod`. Why add an extra package when `addgroup` does the job?